# How to parse json string in airflow template

Tags: airflow

Is it possible to parse JSON string inside an airflow template?

I have a HttpSensor which monitors a job via a REST API, but the job id is in the response of the upstream task which has `xcom_push` marked `True`.

I would like to do something like the following, however, this code gives the error `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'json' is undefined`

```
t1 = SimpleHttpOperator(
    http_conn_id="s1",
    task_id="job",
    endpoint="some_url",
    method='POST',
    data=json.dumps({ "foo": "bar" }),
    xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag,
)

t2 = HttpSensor(
    http_conn_id="s1",
    task_id="finish_job",
    endpoint="job/{{ json.loads(ti.xcom_pull(\"job\")).jobId }}",
    response_check=lambda response: True if response.json().state == "complete" else False,
    poke_interval=5,
    dag=dag
)

t2.set_upstream(t1)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add a custom Jinja filter to your DAG with the parameter [user_defined_filters](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.8.2/airflow/models.py#L2655-L2660) to parse the json.

> a dictionary of filters that will be exposed
>           in your jinja templates. For example, passing
>           `dict(hello=lambda name: 'Hello %s' % name)` to this argument allows
>           you to `{{ 'world' | hello }}` in all jinja templates related to
>           this DAG.

```
dag = DAG(
    ...
    user_defined_filters={'fromjson': lambda s: json.loads(s)},
)

t1 = SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id='job',
    xcom_push=True,
    ...
)

t2 = HttpSensor(
    endpoint='job/{{ (ti.xcom_pull("job") | fromjson)["jobId"] }}',
    ...
)
```

However, it may be cleaner to just write your own custom `JsonHttpOperator` [plugin](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/plugins.html) (or add a flag to `SimpleHttpOperator`) that parses the JSON before [returning](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.8.2/airflow/operators/http_operator.py#L87) so that you can just directly reference `{{ti.xcom_pull("job")["jobId"]` in the template.

```
class JsonHttpOperator(SimpleHttpOperator):

    def execute(self, context):
        text = super(JsonHttpOperator, self).execute(context)
        return json.loads(text)
```

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively, it is also possible to add the `json` module to the template by doing and the json will be available for usage inside the template. However, it is probably a better idea to create a plugin like Daniel said.

```
dag = DAG(
    'dagname',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval="@once",
    user_defined_macros={
        'json': json
    }
)
```

then

```
finish_job = HttpSensor(
    task_id="finish_job",
    endpoint="kue/job/{{ json.loads(ti.xcom_pull('job'))['jobId'] }}",
    response_check=lambda response: True if response.json()['state'] == "complete" else False,
    poke_interval=5,
    dag=dag
)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another new method to achieve the above by setting `render_template_as_native_obj=True` at dag level

```
dag = DAG(
    'dagname',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval="@once",
    render_template_as_native_obj=True   # <------
)

t1 = SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id='job',
    xcom_push=True,
    ...
)

t2 = HttpSensor(
    endpoint='job/{{ (ti.xcom_pull("job")["jobId"] }}',  # <-----
    ...
)
```

Here's the [reference](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/operators.html#rendering-fields-as-native-python-objects)  from Airflow docs!