# How to set a Dynamic name for the job_flow_overrides in Airflow EmrCreateJobFlowOperator?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, airflow, amazon-emr

I am trying to set up an AWS EMR process in Airflow and I need the `job_flow_overrides` in the `EmrCreateJobFlowOperator` and the `steps` in the `EmrAddStepsOperator` to be set by separate JSON files located elsewhere.

I have tried numerous ways both of linking the JSON files directly and of setting and getting Airflow Variables for the JSON.  If I were to use the Airflow Variables, they would also need to be dynamically named, which I am having trouble with. I am able to easily `Variable.set` a dynamic name using a PythonOperator, but cannot `Variable.get` a dynamic name in the `job_flow_overrides` or `steps` because of Airflow's limitations of writing Python code outside of a PythonOperator.

The Airflow Variables have already been set earlier in the code, the following is my code trying to use the JSON data and set up the cluster

```
def get_global_json_contents():
    return json.dumps(requests.get("PATH/TO/JSON/FILE").json())

# Use the 'Name' Key in this JSON as a specific identifier for the Variables created by this job
def get_global_json_name():
    return json.loads(get_global_json_contents())['Name']

cluster_creator = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
    task_id='create_job_flow',
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    emr_conn_id='emr_default',
    job_flow_overrides=json.loads(Variable.get("CLUSTER_SETUP-"+get_global_json_name())),
    dag=dag
)

add_steps = EmrAddStepsOperator(
    task_id='add_steps',
    job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}",
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    steps=json.loads(Variable.get("RUN_STEPS-"+get_global_json_name())),
    dag=dag
)

step_checker = EmrStepSensor(
    task_id='watch_step',
    job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}",
    step_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('add_steps', key='return_value')[0] }}",
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    dag=dag
)

cluster_remover = EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator(
    task_id='remove_cluster',
    job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}",
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    dag=dag
)
```

Does anyone know how I can get this process to work?

Does anyone have an idea how to get around the limitations of not being able to use Python functions in Airflow outside of `PythonOperator` and `python_callable`?

Might it be possible to solve this by defining functions in a separate Python file located elsewhere and importing it to Airflow? And if so, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 4):

*I haven't completely understood the problem here, but from the bits that I've gathered, I can give some ideas*

---

A. If the *dynamism* refers to *frequently (once every few days) changing file-names*

Store the name of file in an Airflow [`Variable`](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=variable) (you seem to have already figured this out)

- refer the name of file from Airflow Variable (rather than hard-coding in dag-definition file)
- and when need arises, you can update the file-name (Variable) via WebUI itself

B. If *dynamism* means *each task / dag-run must process a different file*, then here are the options

1. External system that is generating these JSON files can also update the above-mentioned Airflow Variable so that your tasks can pick the correct file-name. I personally don't like this approach since external system has to become Airflow-aware and also it appears to be error-prone
2. If possible, the external system and Airflow tasks should adhere to some **file-naming convention**, so that we don't even need to communicate the exact filename to task (task already knows how to determine the filename). For instance, you can have your file named as `{execution_date}-{dag_id}-{env}-{task_id}.json`. This approach is relatively good, but only as long as a templatized file-name fits into your system (which might not be the case)
3. The upstream task that gets hold of the exact filename, can convey this information to downstream task via [XCOM](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=variable#xcoms). This approach is most robust of all

---

As for your query

> Does anyone have an idea how to get around the limitations of not
>   being able to use Python functions in Airflow outside of
>   PythonOperator and python_callable?

I think solving this takes just some getting-used-to (and a bit of creativity) with Airflow framework. You can always subclass any Airflow Operator (including [`EmrCreateJobFlowOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/emr_create_job_flow_operator.py)), and then override the [`pre_execute()`, `execute()`, & `post_execute()` methods](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L581) and add your custom logic there

---

Suggested reads

- [EMR Cluster Creation using Airflow dag run, Once task is done EMR will be terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55233359/3679900)
- [Airflow: Lesser Known Tips, Tricks, and Best Practises](https://medium.com/datareply/airflow-lesser-known-tips-tricks-and-best-practises-cf4d4a90f8f)

---

**EDIT-1**

*responding to queries raised over comments*

> I could not get the job_flow_overrides to take an XCOM as input. Do
>   you know how to remedy this?

Knowing that [`job_flow_overrides`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/emr_create_job_flow_operator.py#L39) is a [template field](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L644) of [`EmrCreateJobFlowOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/emr_create_job_flow_operator.py) (the developers of `Airflow` had your use-case in mind), you can employ `JINJA` templating to [pull it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46061162/3679900) via [`XCOM`](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#xcoms)

```
import json
my_dag = DAG(dag_id="my_dag",
             ..
             user_defined_macros={
                 'json': json
             }
             ..
             )
create_emr_task = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(dag_id="my_dag",
                                           task_id="create_emr_task",
                                           ..
                                           job_flow_overrides="{{ json.loads(ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='my_xcom_pusher_task')) }}"
                                           ..)
```

> do you have any examples for using/ overwriting the execute() methods?

Well this now is a pure `python` question. If you have ever done object-oriented programming, particularly [inheritance](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-python/), you will feel home at this.

- This involves just subclassing the [`BaseOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py) (or any subclass of it) and defining your custom functionality in `execute()` function
- For instance, the `PythonOperator` also [extends `BaseOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/python_operator.py#L40)

---

References

- [How to parse json string in airflow template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47528970/3679900)
- [How to Write an Airflow Operator](https://medium.com/@mehmet.vergili/how-to-write-an-airflow-operator-b08b3795e899)

Comment: My initial approach to this issue was to try to use XCOMs. I was able to send an XCOM with the Variable name, but I could not get the `job_flow_overrides` to take an XCOM as input. Do you know how to remedy this? I should be able to make this work smoothly if I could actually get the 'job_flow_overrides' to accept an XCOM.

I should also be able to get something working if I could get `job_flow_overrides` to work using some Python code, even if it just calls a `def` function that passes it a string (which I tried but could not get working due to the running Python code limitations).

Comment: Also, do you have any examples for using/ overwriting the `execute()` methods?  I am new to using both Airflow and Python and could really use the help.  Thanks.

Comment: A COMMENT ON YOUR EDIT-1: I tried running the DAG just as you did, setting `user_defined_macros={ 'json': json }` and `job_flow_overrides="{{ json.loads(ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='python_operator')) }}"` in my code, but the DAG would not run. I got a failure on the `job_flow_overrides` of **Expected type 'dict', got 'str' instead**.

Comment: Please go through the link that i've shared titled "How to parse JSON string in Airflow template"

Comment: I have looked through the links you provided, including the "How to parse JSON string in Airflow template".  I was able to get the process working when using Python Operators, however, I am still having trouble getting this to work within the context of the `job_flow_overrides`.