# Is Variable.get('x', deserialize_json=True) the same as Jinja '{{ var.json.x }}'?

Tags: python, json, airflow

I have a `Variable` stored like this:

```
x | {"a": 1, "b": 2}
```

I want to retrieve this full JSON as a dict in my DAG script. The following works:

```
from airflow.models import Variable
op = CustomOperator(
  templated_field = Variable.get('x', deserialize_json = True)
)
# called in CustomOperator:
templated_field.keys()
# dict_keys(['a', 'b'])
```

The [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=variable) suggests the following should be equivalent:

> The second call [using `Variable.get(deserialize_json=True)`] assumes json content and will be deserialized...
>
> ...or if you need to deserialize a json object from the variable [using a Jinja template]:
>
> `{{ var.json.<variable_name> }}`

However, when I use this and then try to extract the keys, I get error:

```
op = CustomOperator(
  templated_field = '{{ var.json.x }}'
)
# called in CustomOperator
templated_field.keys()
```

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

The error suggests actually the json was not deserialized:

```
# same error
"{'a': 1, 'b': 2}".keys()
```

The only examples of using the `var.json` approach I've found online don't extract a *dict* from JSON, but rather use a JSON path to extract a *scalar*:

```
# https://www.applydatascience.com/airflow/airflow-variables/
{{ var.json.example_variables_config.var3 }}
# https://gist.github.com/kaxil/61f41dd87a69230d1a637dc3a1d2fa2c
{{ var.json.dag1_config.var1 }}
```

Hossein helpfully points out that this field should be templated; here's the line from `CustomOperator`:

```
class CustomOperator(SuperCustomOperator):
    template_fields = SuperCustomOperator.template_fields + ('template_field',)
```

Am I missing something? Is the Jinja `var.json` approach only suitable for extracting scalars, or can it be used to extract JSON-as-dict as well?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47520512/18724793) which helped me with a similar issue of passing a dictionary as variable.
The problem is that Jinja2's `{{ var.json.x }}` echo's the value of `var.json.x`, so it converts the `dict` to `str` which as a side effect changes double-quotes to single-quotes in the json-like str, so you can't directly load the string as json-string.

My solution was adding a custom filter, which renders the dictionary as json string (double quoted where needed) and then I can convert it back to dictionary inside my function.

The code:

```py
dag = DAG(
    ...
    user_defined_filters={'tojson': lambda s: json.dumps(s)},
)

op = PythonOperator(
    ...
    op_kwargs = { "input_dict" : {{ var.json.x | tojson }} }
    # also applicable to other templated fields
    python_callable = func
)

def func(input_dict):
    input_dict = json.loads(input_dict)
    ...
```

It works as expected, and now I can use `input_dict` as dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should use it on the `templated fileds` ! The templated field are the fields that renders by `jinaja`, For example assume this `BashOperator`:

```
Task = BashOperator(
    task_id='bash_task',
    bash_command='echo {{ var.json.x }}', 
    dag=dag,
)
```

Comment: OK thanks for this. I should clarify that it is, in fact, a templated field. Sorry for the confusion; Ive edited my Q to have a more representative example in light of this